# Javascript variable not updating inside the google map finction

Tags: javascript, geolocation

```
var userLatLng = { lat: 20.2970766, lng: -4.5483865 };

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: userLatLng,
        zoom: 14,
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {
                userLatLng.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                userLatLng.lng = position.coords.longitude;
                const pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude,
                };
                map.setCenter(pos);
            }, () => {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
        )
    } else {
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}
```

When `console.log(userLatLng)` inside the function is getting correct result. But outside of the function getting default lat long. seems not updating the variable. any solution for this ?